# Implementing something similar to Unit of Work in Spring Boot based eshopOnContainers

Tags: spring-boot, hibernate, jpa

```
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CancelOrderCommandHandler implements Command.Handler<CancelOrderCommand, Boolean> {

    private final IOrderRepository orderRepository;

    @Override
    public Boolean handle(CancelOrderCommand command) {
        Order order = orderRepository.get(command.getOrderNumber());
        if(order == null)
            return false;
        
        order.SetCancelledStatus();
        orderRepository.geUnitOfWork().saveChanges();
        
        return true;
    }

}
```

In the above code snippet. Similar to the C# based solution I have separated the Persistence and the Domain logic. All the Persistence related code is written in an Infrastructure project and the entity mappings are defined using XML. I followed the same approach for the repositories as well, except the data is retrieved from entityManager instead of the context.

I am seeking some ideas around the unit of work and how to implement the save changes method. If you look at the above code, the saveChanges doesn't even take any parameter, all the changes are tracked by the Entity framework itself. Also the events which are triggered through the mediator, may trigger other entity changes which also need to be persisted with out explicitly passing those entities.  I too was looking in similar lines and wasn't able to find any solution.

Comment: Not sure of the question or the problem, as an EntityManager is a unit of work context tied to a transaction. You've read from the repository, so as long as this 'handle' method is wrapped in a transaction, all changes made to entities read during that transaction will be in the same EntityManager context and saved when the transaction commits.